# Checkbox.checked undefined in OnClick event function

Tags: javascript, html

With the following code both Javascript functions show the .Checked value is undefined. Anyone know why? I need the cb1 checkbox unset when the cb2 checkbox is set and vice versa.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
    function cb2Unset(id){
        box = document.getElementById(id);
        alert(box.Checked);
        if (box.Checked==true){
            testForm.cb2.Checked = false;
        }
    }

    function cb1Unset(id){
        box = document.getElementById(id);
        alert(box.Checked);
        if (box.Checked==true){
            testForm.cb1.Checked = false;
        }
    }
-->
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" name="testForm"> 
    <input checked="checked" value="1" name="cb1" id="cb1" onclick="cb2Unset(this.id)" type="checkbox"> 
    <input value="1" name="cb2" id="cb2" onclick="cb1Unset(this.id)" type="checkbox"> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't radio buttons be better since this is their default behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive language.

It should be `checked` with small letter, i.e. `box.checked`.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a custom <strike>function</strike> ***property*** somewhere it's:

```
element.checked
```

not

```
element.Checked
```

Comment: Why would there be a function? They don't have `()` on the end...

Comment: @Ian I guess he wanted to say `custom property`.

Comment: @Ian - Darnit, you people!

Comment: @adeneo "you people"?!! What's THAT supposed to mean? :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'Checked' property. Try it in lowercase:

```
box.checked == true;
```